# What is meaning of torque about an axis other than the axis of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotation

Torque, for a system of particles, is defined as:

$$\boldsymbol {\tau}_{net} = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf r_i \times \mathbf F_{i,net}$$

Here $\mathbf r_i$ is the position vector of the point from the coordinates axis. Now usually this coordinate axis coincides with the axis of rotation.

- But what if this coordinate axis doesn't coincided with the axis of rotation then what would the value of torque about that axis mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question : [Is torque independent of choice of the point of rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147932)

Comment: @sammy can you please tell what is wrong with the concept?

Comment: See also [Which is the axis of rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52408)

Comment: @sammy I have clarified the question. Please do tell if you think it's still not clear.

Comment: @Sammy suppose we have just one particle and a force of $1N $ acts on it. It can be clearly seen that we can pick up an arbitrary axis such that a torque of $1N.m$ acts whereas for some other axis the torque can be $2 N.m$. Now how can you say that torque is independent of axis?

Comment: As stated in the questions which I have linked, torque is independent of axis of rotation. The co-ordinate system which you have used to calculate torque does not determine what the axis of rotation will be. Torque will be the same about any axis, but how the object responds depends on whether torque is parallel with the axis which is chosen (eg by fixing two points in the object).

Comment: @ Sammy So I think by axis you are trying to mean axis of rotation (?) whereas I, by axis, mean coordinate axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103766/discussion-between-sammy-gerbil-and-johan-liebert).

Comment: More possible duplicates : [What is the physical meaning of torque about an axis outside the body?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417936), [What is the difference when we measure torque/angular momentum about a point and about an axis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218963).

Comment: Related [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499753/392) to a question on the nature of torque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Torques exist independent of rotations. Indeed, in statics problems nothing is rotating, yet we can still choose points of reference to calculate torques about (and show that the net torque about any such point is $0$).

You just pick some reference point, then you apply your definition to determine the torque caused by forces about that point. Of course for certain analysis it is smart to choose the point that coincides with the axis of rotation, but this is not a requirement to apply the definition of torque itself.

This is also found in the definition of angular momentum $\mathbf L=\mathbf r\times\mathbf p$. You can choose any reference point you want to calculate angular momentum about. And you can still write out $\boldsymbol\tau=\text d\mathbf L/\text dt$ about that axis, where the torque and angular momentum are relative to the same axis.

Comment: Can you please continue after: "You just pick some reference point, then you apply your definition to determine the torque caused by forces about that point". So what does the torque about that axis mean? As for now I think that about any arbitrary axis the torque causes increase in angular momentum about that axis and it seems to me that for axis farther from the object the rate of change of angular momentum and is higher(?)). Also can you please tell how any arbitrary axis might be different from the axis of rotation? Thanks (+1 for now)

Comment: *As for now I think that about any arbitrary axis the torque causes increase in angular momentum about that axis* Yes, that is correct. In terms of what it "means" or how one axis is "different" from the axis of rotation, those questions seem somewhat vague to me, and a more specific answer to them would probably need to assume a specific scenario and axis to calculate torques about. But in any case, the part I quoted will always be true, and I think that is a fine way to think of this.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed rotation axis, such as with a car wheel, can only rotate around the axle. An unrestrained object will only rotate about a line through it's center of mass. Applying a force off-center of it's COM will cause rotation and translation.